# rails Initialize new object through associated search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I would like to be able to search for a client from the nav bar and have it automatically provide the WorkOrderController with the associated client. The goal is to automatically generate some of the work order information before the user gets to the new view. I was hoping to do this by making the new work order path nested under clients, but I'm not sure where to turn the form submission into a find to return the client for use in the work order controller. Clearly I am missing a method somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put it and what exactly it is I need it to do.

As far as I can tell what I need to do is somehow have the form submit to some method, which would then redirect to the new work order page with the :client_id in the params.

Am I totally off base here or am I missing something relatively small? An hour and a half of searching didn't turn up much as most guides talk about the form_for functionality. This doesn't appear to be a full on search either.

```
#routes.rb
....
resources :client do
  get 'schedule', to: 'work_order#client_schedule'
  get 'archive', to: 'work_order#client_archive'
  resources :work_order, only: [:new]
end     
.....

#application.html.erb
.....
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter client number">
   </div>
   <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-default">New Work Order</button>
</form>
.....

#WorkOrderController.rb
 ....
def new
  client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  @workorder = WorkOrder.new(client: client)
end
....
```

EDIT:

I made the following change and now when I attempt to load the page I get an error saying I am missing the client_id parameter, though I thought that is what I'm looking for in the first place

```
<%= form_tag new_client_work_order_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter client number"%>
   </div>
   <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-default">New Work Order</button>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2:
Was able to achieve my desired result by doing the following:

In work_order_controller.rb

```
....
def new
  client = Client.find_by(clientnumber: params[:client_number])
  @workorder = WorkOrder.new(client: client)
end
....
```

I switched the routes so that the new route was not nested under client and then  changed the form to be:

```
<%= form_tag new_work_order_path, :method => "get", class: "navbar-form navbar-left" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :client_number, params[:client_number],  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter client number"%>
  </div>
  <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-default">New Work Order</button>
<% end %>
```

I get the impression that I've created some other problem I don't yet see though, but I could just be paranoid

Comment: which is the relation between the two models?

Comment: Client has_many WorkOrders
WorkOrder belongs_to Client

Comment: well if they are related then you should do something like this in your workorder controller to create a new workorder `@workorder = @client.workorders.build` if i assume that you are in a route something like `localhost:3000/clients/1/workorders/new` then it should work, because the `@client` variable should be as a parameter

Comment: @Demi My goal was to be able to use the create/search bar from anywhere. Does that mean I should probably un-nest the resource?

Comment: then you will need to load the `@client` and `@workorder = @client.workorders.build` into the application_controller.rb file, because that controller is loaded before any controller in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning your code quickly, I don't see anything missing and while there's a number of ways to get this done, I think you're on the (a) right track.

Building things like this in Rails involves getting quite a number of components all working together at the same time, so in this case I'd focus on each step in turn (chronologically) to verify that it works as expected. Specifically I'd:

- Watch the Rails console when I click that "New Work Order" button to verify that the `client_id` parameter is "seen" by the controller. (On closer inspection, according to your HTML, I don't see how this form would pass this parameter... or how the form would submit in the first place. Where's the form's `action` attribute?)
- Use `puts` statements in the controller `#new` action to verify that the `client` object is initialized properly and that `@workorder.client_id` is the expected value.
- Add output to the `#new` view template that prints out the `@workorder.client_id` to verify that the ID is carried over to the view. I don't see this view template in the above code snippets so I don't know what you *expect* to show up.

And so forth. Just breaking the problem into smaller steps so they're easier to figure out what's happening. Good luck!

Comment: I suppose where I'm struggling the most is what action I need to use on the form. I think i need to do a Client.find_by and then pass the returned object to the new_client_work_order_path, so would something like that go in the client controller?

Comment: As much as possible, think of the form (that you're submitting) and the controller action (that's handling that submission) as two completely separate things. I'd start by writing out just plain HTML for the form that you'd ideally want, with no Rails helpers. Then once you have that and verified that it works, start using the fancy Rails form helpers to make the form's HTML code more dynamic and reduce repetition. But those helpers are worthless until you 100% understand what HTML you want to end up with.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "what action I need to use on the form", but if you mean what URL should the form POST to, to some extent that's up to you. Rails uses `routes.rb` to define what URL should connect to each controller method, and if you're following the conventions your form's `action` URL will often be something like `/client_work_orders/183` (of course Rails lets you use those wordy route helper methods so you don't have to write that out explicitly). But the important thing is to ensure that when the form submits, it ends up at the right controller action.